# SQL - select last and previous different to last

Tags: sql-server-2016

**The problem**: a simplified membership table containing membership id, starting date for each membership and membership level description:

```
CREATE TABLE cover
(
    [membership_id] int, 
    [cover_from_date] date, 
    [description] varchar(57)
);

INSERT INTO cover ([membership_id], [cover_from_date], [description])
VALUES (1, '1/1/2011', 'AA'),
       (1, '1/2/2011', 'BB'),
       (1, '1/3/2011', 'CC'),
       (1, '1/4/2011', 'CC');
```

**The task**: to list the current membership and the immediate previous membership different to the current one.  So from the above table I would like to see something like:

```
1, 1/4/2011, CC, 1/2/2011, BB
```

**The attempted solution**: I have managed to come up with a solution but it takes an enormous time to run on a large database and I'm sure there are better ways of resolving this problem.  My no-doubt over complicated query is as follows:

```
with cte as 
(
    select
        cover.membership_id, cover.cover_from_date, 
        cover.description, 
        row_number() over (partition by cover.membership_id order by  cover.cover_from_date desc) AS version_no
    from
        cover
)
select 
    cte.membership_id, 
    cover_now.cover_from_date, cover_now.description, 
    cover_prev.cover_from_date, cover_prev.description
from
    cte
left outer join 
    cte cover_now on cte.membership_id = cover_now.membership_id
                  and cover_now.version_no = 1
left outer join 
    cte cover_prev on cte.membership_id = cover_prev.membership_id
                   and cover_prev.version_no = (select min(x.version_no)
                                                from  cte x
                                                where x.version_no >= 2
                                                  and x.membership_id = cover_now.membership_id
                                                  and x.description <> cover_now.description)
group by 
    cte.membership_id, cover_now.cover_from_date, cover_now.description, 
    cover_prev.cover_from_date, cover_prev.description
```

The entire fiddle is located [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10396/5).  Any tips on how to optimise the query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an index on membership_id and cover_from_date in descending order. It will be heavily used by this query.

```
create index cover_by_date on cover (membership_id asc, cover_from_date desc)
```

Then:

```
select
   membership.membership_id,
   membership.cover_from_date,
   membership.description,
   previous_membership.cover_from_date,
   previous_membership.description
from 
   (
      select membership_id, description, cover_from_date, row_number() over (partition by membership_id order by cover_from_date desc) as rank
      from cover
   ) as membership
   left join (
      select previous.membership_id, previous.description, previous.cover_from_date, row_number() over (partition by previous.membership_id order by previous.cover_from_date desc) as rank
      from cover
         join cover as previous on
            cover.membership_id = previous.membership_id and
            cover.description <> previous.description and
            cover.cover_from_date > previous.cover_from_date
   ) as previous_membership on
      previous_membership.membership_id = membership.membership_id and
      previous_membership.rank = 1
where
   membership.rank = 1
```